# Hide one word at a time with overflow:hidden

Tags: css

Is there a way to use CSS hide a word at a time (instead of a letter at a time) when an element isn't wide enough to show it's text content?

For example, with the following code, when the browser window gets to narrow to show the entire sentence, I want it to show `Lorem ipsum dolor sit...` instead of `Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame...`

HTML:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space-nowrap; }
```

(I don't need to support old browsers)

Comment: I've done some research and it doesn't seem possible. :( I'd love to know if it is possible, though!

Comment: This would work with Javascript

Comment: @Markasoftware, I've thought of a way to do it with Javascript, just wondering if a CSS approach is possible.

Comment: maybe `ellipsis-word`: http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/

Comment: `ellipsis-word` would have been perfect, but doesn't seem to have been implemented in any browser as yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always just force your container to have the same height as a single line of text, and just hide whatever text wraps beneath that line using `overflow: hidden`.

```css
/* hide one word at a time */

p.short {
    height: 18px;
    overflow: hidden; }

/* display an ellipsis "..." */

p.ellipsis { 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/fbhxL/

Comment: Thanks Wex. That approach doesn't keep the '...' from my example, but it does answer my question. I'll accept this if nobody can offer a solution that keeps the dots.

Comment: Yeah, it's too bad you can't chain pseudo-selectors or you could probably do something like `p::first-line::after`